# Multiple callbacks when using Quicksand

Tags: jquery, callback, quicksand

I'm using Quicksand for a sortable portfolio page and need to remove the left padding of every third element using nth-child also I have to add a mouseover and mouseout effect.
This is what I have at present:

```
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
}, function () {
    $("#center_content .portfolio .tiles_holder .four img").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3, function () {
            $('ul.tiles_holder li:nth-child(3n+1)').css("marginLeft", "0");
        });
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1, function () {
            $('ul.tiles_holder li:nth-child(3n+1)').css("marginLeft", "0");
        });
    });
});
```

But what happens is the margin isn't removed until the mouseover/out event occurs. How can I improve the code?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the margin left of every 3rd element independant of the mouseover/out?  What do you want to do on the hover on/off?

Comment: Yes I need to remove the margin of every 3rd element for proper layout and the mouseover/out function show extra info about the project when one hovers over the image ( the info is in the background of the image, so reducing the opacity makes it visible )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post any html, it is hard to say exactly but it seems like you need to change the quicksand callback to this:

```
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
}, function () {

   $('ul.tiles_holder li:nth-child(3n+1)').css("marginLeft", "0");

    $("#center_content .portfolio .tiles_holder .four img").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked... 
I had also unsuccessfuly tried :
<code>
    $("#center_content .portfolio .tiles_holder .four img").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }, function (){//n-th child code }); );</code>
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The part that removes the margin left needs to be outside the mouseover/out events because it is independent of them.  The events are just fading in and out your image not related to the margin left.